# Scraping a lift with Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and trying to write some code that scrapes information form a website. I currently have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

for i in range(1, 300):
    url = "[REMOVED]/footwear?page=%s" % i

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
items = soup.find_all('div', 'product-block__info')
for item in items:
    for val in item.find_all('a','product-block'):
        stock = item.find_all('class','count_product_stock hidden')[0].text
        brand = item.find_all('div','brand')[0].text
        price = item.find_all('span','selling_price')[0].text

    print (items)
```

Which returns the error `IndexError: list index out of range`. If I put 'product-block__info' in the place of 'product-block' then I am able to print off the full list of the content within the 'product-block__info' tag on the page, but I'd like to just select a handful of elements and return these.

Can anyone explain to me what's happening here and how I can select just the elements i want from inside 'product-block__info'?

Comment: The url would be helpful so we can figure out class names etc.

Comment: try 
    `soup.find_all('div', class_='product-block__info')`

Comment: Replacing my code with the above isn't having any noticeable change in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting attributes with `find_all` you should either use the `attrs` dictionary or the [keyword arguments](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments), otherwise `bs4` is lookink for tags.

```
for i in range(1, 300):
    url = "[REMOVED]/footwear?page=%s" % i
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-block__info')
    for item in items:
        stock = item.find('span', class_='count_product_stock hidden').text
        brand = item.find('h4', class_='brand').text
        price = item.find('span', class_='selling_price').text
        print(stock, brand, price)
```

Comment: Always glad to help:)